# Newsletter appears with white lines when you forward it to another email

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I created a newsletter with photoshop and Dreamweaver.  I use the slice tools to edit certain parts of the newsletter. When I receive the newsletter everything is ok and looks good.  When I forward it to another email, then everything is uneven and there's a big white line where I used the slice tool.

I use

td img { display:block;) code but it doesn't take effect when I forward the email.   Here is the code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
td img {
display: block;
}
</style>
<title>COMEME</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (COMEME.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="613" height="2101" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin: 0 auto 0 auto;">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="16">
   <a href="https://comemearreglos.com/">
    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/b2337bae-4f09-4cbd-a86c-36d9a75a69be.jpg" width="612" height="298" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="1" height="298" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="16">
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/d388fb87-d763-489d-8357-58611c94338a.jpg" width="612" height="59" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="1" height="59" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="16">
   <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWXPkCBUFnYa">
    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/609b07a7-1537-4808-bdd5-9e0075aad773.jpg" width="612" height="349" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="1" height="349" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="16">
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/d5734d30-bbff-4612-97a5-bf0d06974ea9.jpg" width="612" height="17" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="1" height="17" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="7">
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/ff459b85-e0b4-4746-baee-08f8a866c5a4.jpg" width="252" height="234" alt=""></td>
  <td colspan="8" rowspan="2">
   <a href="https://comemearreglos.com/collections/dia-de-las-madres/products/florecer-de-margaritas">
    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/71ff2c8f-a5c2-4640-8d8a-6a7d9b1ce5ff.jpg" width="353" height="518" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
  <td rowspan="4">
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/850e2f71-cfeb-4e4c-8b2b-23f56afca360.jpg" width="7" height="599" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="1" height="234" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="7" rowspan="2">
   <a href="https://comemearreglos.com/collections/dia-de-las-madres/products/alegria-de-margarita">
    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/faf69cb1-f878-4f53-8786-62580a2214e6.jpg" width="252" height="345" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="1" height="284" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="8" rowspan="2">
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/c256f1f3-896d-4e39-8823-5d96361f79d3.jpg" width="353" height="81" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="1" height="61" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="7">
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/25661d89-4fb7-402d-a7d5-69333c050f54.jpg" width="252" height="20" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="1" height="20" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="4">
   <a href="https://comemearreglos.com/collections/dia-de-las-madres/products/ramo-bombon-grande">
    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/078da33a-90f6-4b9c-ba95-bfd6930a2888.jpg" width="204" height="264" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
  <td colspan="8">
   <a href="https://comemearreglos.com/collections/dia-de-las-madres/products/abanico-de-margaritas">
    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/2ec18a16-da30-4998-98e5-2222e7d50d1a.jpg" width="204" height="264" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
  <td colspan="4">
   <a href="https://comemearreglos.com/collections/dia-de-las-madres/products/caja-sorpresa">
    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/c2f034a3-9c6a-493d-a877-1f5179f198f0.jpg" width="204" height="264" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="1" height="264" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="6">
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/7d0e5d3f-bd0c-42e4-b9c3-d5d3815459b2.jpg" width="3" height="514" alt=""></td>
  <td colspan="4">
   <a href="https://comemearreglos.com/products/corazon-de-fresa-normal">
    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/5cbd5ac8-eba3-49e7-ae7c-98455ef803e0.jpg" width="203" height="294" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
  <td colspan="8">
   <a href="https://comemearreglos.com/collections/dia-de-las-madres/products/ramo-sorpresa">
    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f961ee13-9185-416b-ae26-234ff3ff171f.jpg" width="219" height="294" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
  <td colspan="3">
   <a href="https://comemearreglos.com/collections/dia-de-las-madres/products/kyara">
    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/319c70e6-0880-497e-9fd0-42eb101065e9.jpg" width="187" height="294" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="1" height="294" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="15">
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/093c362d-72ae-48b9-8d2f-273fcf08b010.jpg" width="609" height="76" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="1" height="76" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/565d44c0-88c8-46e8-ac3e-a5266ac185a5.jpg" width="190" height="96" alt=""></td>
  <td colspan="8">
   <a href="https://comemearreglos.com/">
    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/bec9d089-7f39-46d3-a7b9-7e125b5d1806.jpg" width="205" height="37" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
  <td colspan="5" rowspan="2">
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/614847c7-6dca-42df-8f28-c0fb7d46a342.jpg" width="214" height="96" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="1" height="37" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="8">
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/b2498e85-f1a1-4141-84d9-cef2157d7436.jpg" width="205" height="59" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="1" height="59" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="2">
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/2f9ad99a-57db-4455-bb47-33e8268f8605.jpg" width="183" height="48" alt=""></td>
  <td colspan="4">
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/2748320c-5a61-4321-a0c5-d7ee800ca95a.jpg" width="45" height="41" alt=""></td>
  <td colspan="2">
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/36cb6fe6-5e0d-4129-93ee-ab3cc76a4be6.jpg" width="44" height="41" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/acomeme">
    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/1524864e-1691-4dc5-b348-f8c2f127a034.jpg" width="44" height="41" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
  <td>
   <a href="https://www.instagram.com/comemearreglos/">
    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/9fe75a76-b488-4a99-bedd-018154afbbf8.jpg" width="44" height="41" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
  <td colspan="2">
   <a href="https://es.pinterest.com/arregloscomeme/">
    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/e75c1785-63c1-4d29-8f7b-ca052c56985a.jpg" width="45" height="41" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
  <td colspan="2">
   <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/ComemeArreglos">
    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/1de8b935-c5b4-4ca1-b292-1f94fe5ca573.jpg" width="44" height="41" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
  <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/07cfe6db-5679-4694-b24a-87884f4c1410.jpg" width="160" height="48" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="1" height="41" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="12">
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/2e95bd34-40d0-4c96-af9b-d81a9f6b60ae.jpg" width="266" height="7" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="1" height="7" alt=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="3" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="183" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="7" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="11" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="2" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="25" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="21" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="23" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="44" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="44" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="35" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="10" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="17" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="27" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="153" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td>
   <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/08b86230a708119be4d19046b/images/f89c7286-9433-4041-9674-c395f9073d04.gif" width="7" height="1" alt=""></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
            <center>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="canspamBarWrapper" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top:1px solid #E5E5E5;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="canspamBar">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#606060; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:11px; line-height:150%; padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left:20px; text-align:center;">
                                        This email was sent to <a href="mailto:*|EMAIL|*" target="_blank" style="color:#404040 !important;">*|EMAIL|*</a>
                                        <br>
                                        <a href="*|ABOUT_LIST|*" target="_blank" style="color:#404040 !important;"><em>why did I get this?</em></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="*|UNSUB|*" style="color:#404040 !important;">unsubscribe from this list</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="*|UPDATE_PROFILE|*" style="color:#404040 !important;">update subscription preferences</a>
                                        <br>
                                        *|LIST:ADDRESSLINE|*
                                        <br>
                                        <br>
                                        
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <style type="text/css">
                    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                        table#canspamBar td{font-size:14px !important;}
                        table#canspamBar td a{display:block !important; margin-top:10px !important;}
                    }
                </style>
            </center></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well you put a ton of `<br>`s in there, so...

Comment: @Siguza Photoshop and Dreamweaver did this automatically